# Append value into textbox dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

I have button using an HTML `a` tag. I have a button which has a value of `10`. If I click on this button 2 times, the value is appended into the first textbox as `2` and second textbox as `20` (value of button (10) * no of button click (2))

Same as if I click 3 times, the value is appended into first textbox as `3` and the second textbox as `30` (value of button (10) * no of button clicks (3))

```
10 * 2 = 20

10 * 3 = 30
```

Above scenario is for append value into textbox at runtime onclick of button.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For example,10 *2 = 20. Now 10 is button worth value is 10,if so now "2" is no of times button click and 20 as value of button 10 and no of time button click "2".  So 2 and 20 is append dynamically into textbox.

Comment: I don't know how your HTML or JS looks like but I made a small fiddle with jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/3coLdkfg/4/

Comment: Thanks swidmann .not exactly but I hope your logic works for me.let me try with your logic

Comment: Hey Rory,Please refer any e-commerce website's. Cart page - in this if we click on any product it will show value for quantity and amount dynamically.for example,you click on product 2 times,then qty reflects as 2 and amount= product price* qty.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this: https://jsfiddle.net/0r0ewwhq/10/

```
<body>
    <button id="addButton" value="10">Add</button>
    <button id="delButton" value="10">Remove</button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="count" name="count"/>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="value" name="value"/>
</body>


$("#addButton").on( "click", function(e) {
    $("#count").val( parseInt( $("#count").val() ) + 1 );
    $("#value").val( parseInt( $("#count").val() ) * parseInt( $(this).val()) );
});

$("#delButton").on( "click", function(e) {
    if (parseInt($("#count").val()) > 0)
    {
        $("#count").val( parseInt( $("#count").val() ) - 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        $("#count").val(0);
    }
    $("#value").val( parseInt( $("#count").val() ) * parseInt( $(this).val()) );
});
```